# How to see the log files of msi package installation?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I am trying to install mongoDB msi package but the setup fails and rollsback.
Where can i see the log files?

Answer (score 3):

The package can be run using msiexec like this:

```
msiexec /i "<the package>.msi" /l*v "install.log"
```